# JanusGraph 1.0.0, gremlin console getting serializer error

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have configured New JanusGraph janusgraph-full-1.0.0-rc1 on centos 7 with janusgraph-cql-es.
But when i am connecting using apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.8/bin/gremlin.sh
it is throwing following exception :
after remote console

```
> g.V();

WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer  - Response [PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 57, widx: 57, cap: 57)] could not be deserialized by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 127 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.util.MapReferenceResolver.getReadObject(MapReferenceResolver.java:60)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readReferenceOrNull(Kryo.java:834)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:684)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.deserializeResponse(AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.java:157)
```

And its also throwing error on server

```
08:40:45 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.select - Gremlin Server is not configured with a serializer for the requested mime type [application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd] - using org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1 by default
08:40:45 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.decode - Serialization error while decoding request
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: The most significant bit should be set according to the format
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.binary.RequestMessageSerializer.readValue(RequestMessageSerializer.java:45) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1.deserializeRequest(GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1.java:175) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.decode(WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.java:77) ~[gremlin-server-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
```

Need guidance on what is correct config that needs to be done, so that janusgraph works properly and i am able to access data using gremlin console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not every JanusGraph version is compatible with every TinkerPop version. The JanusGraph documentation contains [a *Version Compatibility Matrix*](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/changelog/#version-compatibility) which shows the versions of other projects that are compatible with a given JanusGraph version. For JanusGraph 1.0, the compatible TinkerPop versions are 3.6.z. This already explains why you are having problems with Gremlin Console in version 3.4.8. Please use a 3.6.z version of Gremlin Console if you want to use JanusGraph 1.0.

Your concrete problem between these two versions is that the Gryo MessageSerializer that you are using with Gremlin Console 3.4.8 [is not supported any more in JanusGraph 1.0](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/changelog/#drop-support-for-gryo-messageserializer). This problem should however go away when you use Gremlin Console 3.6 as that also does not use Gryo any more as a message serializer.

Also note that JanusGraph 1.0.0-rc1 is a release candidate for the upcoming 1.0.0 release. This means that this version is not meant to be used in production, but only to try out the upcoming release. You can of course still use it as you like, but you should expect some rough edges.

Comment: Thanks Florian for quick detail response, i will test it with Gremln Console 3.6 and confirm.

Comment: Thanks Florian, i verified with apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.6.2 and i am not seeing the excecpion in logs.  Thanks for quick response

Comment: Hi Florian, Just want to check on planned release date for Production of JanusGraph 1.0.0-rc1.

Comment: There is no fixed release date yet, but I would expect it in the following weeks roughly.